# PHP Paypal button error message on quantity

Tags: php, button, paypal, shopping-cart, payment

I have implemented a paypal checkout. Unfortunately I keep getting the following paypal error when I checkout...

> "You have entered an invalid quantity value. A quantity value must be
>   an integer greater than or equal to one."

I don't know why this error occurs because the quantity values are always integers grater than or equal to 1. I even tried enforcing all quantities to 1, however I still get the error. Below is my code. Your help will be much appreciated.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array']) || count($_SESSION['cart_array']) < 1){
        $cart_output = '<div class="pageerror">No items in the cart! </div>';
    }else{
        //paypal checkout button setup
        //proper URL for paypal form action:
        //https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        $paypal_btn .= '<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"  method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="BUTTONID">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@email.com">';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item){
            $itemID = $each_item['itemid'];

                    ///////////////DISPLAY ITEMS CODE////////////////

            //paypal checkout button setup cont..
            $x = $i + 1;
            $paypal_btn .=  '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_' . $x . '" value="' . $name . '">
                            <input type="hidden" name="on0_' . $x . '" value="' . $each_item['size']. '">
                            <input type="hidden" name="amount_' . $x . '" value="' . $price . '">
                            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_' . $x . '" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '"> ';
            $item_id_array = $itemID.'-'.$each_item['quantity'].',';

            //output all item information into table cells
            $cart_output .= '<tr>';
            $cart_output .= '<td><a href="item_details.php?id='.$each_item['itemid'].'"><img src="img/items/'.$itemID.'.jpg" alt="'. $name.'"></a>';
            //$cart_output .= 'Item id: '.$each_item['itemid'].'<br>';
            $cart_output .= '<div class="name">'.$name. '</div></td>';
            //$cart_output .= 'Item: '.$i.' <br>';
            $cart_output .= '<td>'.$desc. '</td>';
            $cart_output .= '<td>'.$each_item['size'].'</td>';
            $cart_output .= '<td> &#163 '.$price.'</td>';
            $cart_output .= '<td>'.$each_item['quantity'].'</td>';
            $cart_output .= '<td> &#163 '.$item_total.'</td>';
            $cart_output .= '<td><a class="remove" href="shopping_cart.php?remove=true&index='.$i.'"><img src="img/x.png"></a></td>';
            $cart_output .= '</tr>';
            $i++;

            /*while(list($key, $value) = each($each_item)){
                $cart_output .= $key.': '.$value. '<br>';
            }*/
        }
        $cart_output .= '<a href="shopping_cart.php?empty=true">Empty Cart</a>'; 
        mysql_close();
        //paypal checkout button setup final.
        $paypal_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $item_id_array . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.student.city.ac.uk/~abnd200/qualitas/core/paypalipn.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.student.city.ac.uk/~abnd200/qualitas/core/checkout_complete.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to The Store">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.student.city.ac.uk/~abnd200/qualitas/core/paypal_cancel.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
        <input type="image" value="Buy Now" src="img/paypal.png" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and secure!">
        </form>';
```

I am using Paypal Sandbox to test the system

Comment: The issue seems to be the paypal sandbox url which my assigned to the "action" variable in my form. It works fine on the default paypal URL. My sandbox account is not fully set up.